# Android studio non-stop moving image from both sides

Tags: android

I have an image, which is a bee. I want to add an animation that make the bee look like it is randomly flying up and down within a specified area. The bee should only fly within `paddingTop="200dp"` to `paddingTop="370dp"`. When it reaches the left of the screen, it should fly back to the right of the screen. And it should be non-stop moving from both sides. However, I can only make it fly or move horizontally with a specified time period.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/bee"
    android:paddingTop="200dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/beeFaceRight" />
```

The code in Main.java

```
 ObjectAnimator animation;
 ImageView bee;

 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    bee = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bee);

    animation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(bee, "translationX", 100f);
    animation.setDuration(2000);
    animation.start();
 }
```

I have tried this, but it does not work.

```
 ObjectAnimator objectX;
 ObjectAnimator objectY;
 AnimatorSet animatorXY;

 objectX = ObjectAnimator.offFloat(bee, "translationX", 0);
 objectY = ObjectAnimator.offFloat(bee, "translationY", 200);
 animatorXY.playTogether(objectX, objectY);
 animatorXY.setDuration(500);
 animatorXY.start();
```